# Should Stack Exchange have the same alignment with and without a scroll bar?

Tags: discussion, design, scrolling

If a page is shorter than one screen (except for the footer, which makes it exactly one screen long), then the scroll bar disappears (I'm using Chrome on Windows 7). But that shifts the whole page a bit to the right, making it not aligned with e.g. other tabs with longer pages in them.

Is that an issue of this website that could be fixed or is it unavoidable?

Comment: @PatrickHofman sounds like it is (OP is long time user and is familiar with the whole SE network), but I have no clue what is being asked here. (aka totally unclear)

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be fixed but I'm sure the dev team shouldn't spend time on this in the next 6 to 8 weeks, or the 6 to 8 weeks following that.

Comment: This is standard browser behaviour that occurs on any site at all with a full-width or centered layout. It's never worth considering as a “bug” that should be fixed -- it's not a problem. It's just a thing that happens.

Answer (score 4):

It's not unfixable, but it's such a small issue (and expected behaviour) that I doubt Stack Exchange will (or should) do anything about it.

If you really want to, you can make a relatively easy (although not perfect) fix with...

```
html { margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%); }
```

That's because `vw` accounts for scrollbars, but `%` doesn't. So if there are scrollbar, the `html` element gets an opposite margin equal to the size of those scrollbars to compensate.

This does mean you'll get white space on the opposite side of the screen instead but at least you don't have the shift. This doesn't affect the top bar either since it has a fixed position. We can target the top bar individually though...

```
header.top-bar { padding-left: calc(100vw - 100%); }
```

So add this to a user stylesheet...

```
html { margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%); }
header.top-bar { padding-left: calc(100vw - 100%); }
```

Comment: That `calc` stuff is CSS3 right?

Comment: @rene it is. support is pretty good though: https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc (mostly supported everywere but IE8 and older Android)

Comment: @Cai IE10 also doesn't support it, only IE11 and above. (i.e. Edge.)

Comment: @Sha are you sure? https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc says otherwise. I havn't got IE in front of me to check now but I'm sure I've used it OK in IE

Comment: @Cai oh, I was in "Current aligned" tab so IE10 or IE9 weren't there at all. Yes, I see IE10 also supports it, but IE9 has only partial support.

Answer (score 2):

I think the minor shift there might be is not an issue SE should spend any time on.

Really, there are more important things to fix than a small shift among tabs which behave different across all browser vendors, versions and operating systems.